# How to turn on "sudo" in OSX 10.12 Sierra

Tags: terminal, macos, sudo, administrator

When I type "sudo some_command", the terminal shows:

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

my account is an admin account, and the /etc/sudoers contains:

```
root        ALL = (ALL) ALL
%admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l /etc/sudoers`

Comment: @patrix the output is `-r--r-----+ 1 root  wheel  1563 Jan 11 10:42 /etc/sudoers`

Comment: Uhh, `ls -le /etc/sudoers` and `ls -led /etc`  as well then, please

Comment: @patrix `-rw-rw-r--+ 1 root wheel 1563 Jan 11 10:42 /etc/sudoers 0: group:admin allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity` and `lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Dec 10 21:13 /etc -> private/etc`

Comment: Did it ever work? The ACL seems a bit strange (I don't have one on this file), but I'm not sure whether this causes any issues (and am reluctanct to try it here).

Comment: @patrix After reinstalling OSX Sierra, it finally works. I really don't know what's wrong with sudo.

Comment: 2c tip: use `visudo` for editing sudoers.

Answer (score 7):

Open up Terminal and enable root with:

```
dsenableroot -u <your_admin_username> -p <your_password> -r <root_password> #choose some root password here
```

If the sudoer's is damaged, you still won't be able to `sudo` - but you will be able to `su` and repair the permissions accordingly:

```
su #when asked afterwards enter the above <root_password>
chown root:wheel /etc/sudoers
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
chmod -a "admin allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextatt‌​r,readsecurity" /etc/sudoers
exit
```

Back in your admin account disable root:

```
dsenableroot -d -u <your_admin_username> -p <your_password>
```

---

In case the above won't help, re-enable root account doing the same as above, logut of your account, login as `root` (yup, really):

Open terminal and type `chmod g+x /`, close the term, logout and tada, sudo is working again :) This problem happens mostly when you mount your `/` through linux in rw mode (for `hfsplus` in r/w mode use fuse and `bindfs`)

---

BTW the *group admin* ACL doesn't seem to harm the sudoers file!

Comment: Better boot into single user mode for this no need to enable root

Comment: And do what from the single user login exactly? You need to know how to move around launchctl/diskarbitrioned (since you are in `ro` mount) and doing `mount -rw /` and then `visudo` won't solve this.

Comment: @mark Might be worth another answer then

Comment: @PJJ OK I heavily modified your answer ;-) - but after the second dsenableroot line you shouldn't be able to login as root. You either have to run `chmod g+x /` in su mode or you have to move your last sentence in front of the 2nd dsenableroot line. Also: this shouldn't be necessary in Sierra!

Comment: True, true, overseen that- modded hopefully that won't be all too confusing ;) - most of the times it's `chmod g+x /` since h4x0rs confuse darwin with linux and map happily their guids over darwins realizing later that in darwin guids start from 500 instead of 1000 ;)

Comment: But the comment section of the **question** is somehow doubtful: Desmond Chen's comment on Jan 11 at 15:40 shows another ls output for the sudoers file than Desmond Chen's comment on Jan 12 at 1:29! The "first" sudoers file should work.

Comment: yeah, the one listed on 12th is wrong, should be `chmod 440` and is 644 o.O instead

Comment: Invalid permission type 'writeextatt​r',when trying to use chmod -a "admin allow read...etc etc etc :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a high-level steps:

```
$ dsenableroot -u <user-username> -p <your-user-password> -r <new-password-for-root>
```

Then create a backup of the sudoers file and edit

```
$ su
Password:<your-new-root-password>
sh-3.2# cp /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.bak
sh-3.2# vi /etc/sudoers.bak
sh-3.2# cp /etc/sudoers.bak /etc/sudoers
sh-3.2# exit
```

Last disable root access:

```
$ dsenableroot -d -u abdi -p <root-password>
dsenableroot:: ***Successfully disabled root user.
```